# Using Schema.org to represent Person, Google's Webmaster Tools doesn't see it

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org

I set a bunch of pages about people with the Schema.org type `Person`.

The testing tool sees the metadata perfectly.

However, the Webmaster Tools search appearance says there's no structured data on my site.

Comment: The structured data count in Webmaster Tools has been a little buggy lately. But if you post a URL or two of pages that you've marked up, we could double check things for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Google's help document on rich snippet markup](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750)

> In general, Google will use only marked-up data that is visible to the user. Hidden data will be ignored.

I see in your page source you have something like:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="LarraHeart" ></meta>
<meta itemprop="additionalName" content="larraheart" ></meta>
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://cdn-i.highwebmedia.com/roomimage/larraheart.jpg" ></meta>
<meta itemprop="jobTitle" content="webcam performer" ></meta>
<meta itemprop="nationality" content=" Ukraine "></meta>
<meta itemprop="gender" content=" female "></meta>
```

Meta tags are *NOT* visible.  So the schema markup in them will be ignored by Google.  Instead, you should mark up these items in place where they are on your page.

You should do markup like this:

```
see <span itemprop="name" content="LarraHeart">LarraHeart</span> on Chaturbate now!
```

The content contained within the tags doesn't have to match exactly, but it should mean the same thing.  For example, it is acceptable to use `content="female"` while presenting "one hot babe" to users.

Comment: that's interesting. in that case why would the testing tool give a positive recognition on the invisible tags? will try out your way. thanks!

Comment: That requirement is Google's requirement.  It doesn't make the markup less correct when you use meta tags, but it means that Google won't use it.

Comment: Note that `span` (or any other element, except `meta`) [can’t have a `content` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27089168/1591669) in Microdata.